# How do I create and format a CSV file using Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm working on a program that will combine three different .csv files into one .csv file to be the final export. The purpose of this is to automate some needless copying and pasting time-consuming formatting that we were doing by hand before. The output will be a list of IPs and I would prefer that everything was in one row.

Currently it exports a file with the correct column headers and the correct IPs, however each section is inserted as a new column and this creates formatting issues when copying the list of IPs and pasting them into our software. I would like the end result to be the same list of IPs with the same column headers, but just one long list.

Like this:
Printers
IP1
IP2
...
Network Devices
IP1
IP2
...
Other
IP1
IP2
...

I hope that explanation makes sense, please let me know if it doesn't...
This is the code that I have currently:

```
combinedFile = pd.concat([printersFile, netDevFile, otherFile], axis=1)
combinedFileName = hospitalName + "Exclude"
combinedFile.to_csv(combinedFileName + ".csv", index=False)
print("Check to see if the new files exist!")
```

Please let me know if something doesn't make sense or if you need to see more of the code. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you are actually trying to write three separate DataFrames to one file. You could do the following:

```
with open(combinedFileName + ".csv", "w") as f:
      f.write("\nPrinters:\n" )
      printersFile.to_csv(f,  index=False)

      f.write("\nNetwork Devices:\n" , index=False)
      netDevFile.to_csv(f)

      f.write("\nOther Devices:\n" , index=False)
      otherFile.to_csv(f)
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm getting an error when I try this code "PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'ShadysideExclude.csv'". And I have this issue no matter what the name of the csv file is. I assume its something to do with writing to a file that doesn't exist, or something like that but I am a Python noob and I'm not sure what the issue is.

Comment: I have corrected my answer. this should fix it. It needed write permission. I have added it